# Azure Form Recognizer - Copy model from QA to PROD

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

Our team has built more than 1000+ models in development environment and tested the output. We moved the models from QA to Production using StartModelCopyTo method using Form Recognizer client SDK. During each copy model, code is written such a way that if PercentageCompleted is 100%, then move to next model. All 1000+ models copied to production service. Now the problem is, when we use GetCustomModels method to list all models, all models comes as null, but if I use model Id, it returns all details. Has anyone faced this issue? Business team considers this as an issue and not ready to sign off. We are facing other issues with the Form Recognizer service too.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the SDK/REST API version you are using for the get operation. Can you validate that you are using the API version and SDK that corresponds to the V2.1 or v3 API based on which version the mode was trained with?

Direct message if you are still having trouble.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We are working with MS Support,  its going on for while.  No success yet.  Training models are built using V2.1 and migrating the models using V2.1

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support came back and said that copy model method has threshold of 1 per minute.  Now we created a delay of 1 per minute and it works.